# как совместить 2 строчки в одну в django - urls.py

Tags: html, python, django

совместить из 2 в 1

**urls.py --->**

```
   path('silki/', userViews.SilkiPage.as_view(), name='silki'),
   path('silki/', userViews.silki, name='silki'),
```

**views.py--->**

```
class SilkiPage(ListView):
    model = Silki
    template_name = 'users/silki.html'
    context_object_name = 'silki'
    ordering = ['id']

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(SilkiPage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['text2'] = 'ссылка 2222'
        return ctx



def silki (request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SilkiForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('silki')

    else:
        form = SilkiForm()

        return render(request, 'users/silki.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Что значит "совместить"? Какой результат вы хотите?

Comment: SilkiPage.as_view() - у меня отбражает только, то что есть
userViews.silki - имеет форму для заполнения , 
выполняется либо одно либо другое так как это на одной странице, надо чтобы и то и то функционировало одновременно

Comment: Ну а что мешает убрать `class SilkiPage(ListView)`, смысл которого лично я тут не нахожу, и запихнуть все в `silki(request)`?